# Lumen: How to access api from zend framework?

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, lumen

Suppose there is an API developed by Lumen and a legacy code based in Zend framework. Assuming both code bases reside in the same server, how can I make api calls from Zend to Lumen. I hope to find a way like:

```
// Zend receives request, it does what it should, time to call api
# create lumen app and/or request
$api = whatever;
$request = crate it with proper vars;
# make the call to the specified rout
```

Besides the fact that it might be viable or not, I want to know if there is any other proper/fast way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to go on this problem is through an http call.

You should use a Zend_Http_Client to call the other api done with Lumen, as if it was a third party api.

Comment: It can be my final solution. However endpoints are JWT token protected. I have the secret token, but I don't believe generating token from zend framework is the way to go.